# linux boots but windows doesn't

Tags: linux, windows, boot, hardware-failure

On my computer I have 3 OSs , Ubuntu, W7 and W8. Both Windows won't boot, won't boot into any rescue or safe mode (on W7 it stops after printing loading `classpnp.sys`, I think I tried every solution under the sun which gets suggested when using that as part of my search for answers). It won't even run a W7 install USB which works fine on other computers.

Both times this has happened it was the first time after I got back from a LAN, both times I didn't notice my Windows OSs weren't booting for a few days because I only use Windows for games or testing and some rare C# development. The previous time after trying to fix it for most of a night it suddenly started working after selecting 'run under last known good configuration' but  that also doesn't work this time. My guess it was just a fluke and the intermittent problem just stopped being there.

The two things I haven't done (but am working on doing) which may give more information is:

- Try and run Windows in a virtual machine in Ubuntu
- run Windows off my drives on other computers
- finding a friend with a Haswell CPU and swapping my CPU with his and see if it works.

I am leaning towards thinking it is a hardware issue because it has come and gone effecting multiple OSs at the same time or not at all and my computer is less than 1 month old.

The only thing that would make sense in my mind (but I'm stumped so take this at face value) is that my CPU has a fault in it which only happens when certain instruction (sets) are used which Ubuntu doesn't use hence it still boots without a problem.

Anybody have any suggestions where to start looking for an answer?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just realized I never answered added the eventual solution to the problem.

The final problem was with the graphics card. There were problems with the connection to the motherboard. Reseating the graphics card and cleaning the connectors fixed the issue. My only guess would be that with the different drivers it didn't matter on linux.

Answer (score 1):

That is unusual, I haven't heard of Ubuntu not using a CPU to it's full potential. Intermittent problems can be caused by faulty ram, maybe a full round of memtest testing could help rule out a hardware (cpu/ram) issue. And of course try checking the hard drive(s) for errors.

I do know that different computers can be picky when it comes to bootable USB devices, maybe the BIOS can't or doesn't want to use your windows USB. And usb wires/plugs/devices can be buggy too. I'd try a known good windows dvd and see if that boots.

About Ubuntu vs windows, I have heard of it not using graphics as fully as windows so maybe there's a graphics issue that windows makes happen? But I thought safe mode was supposed to do things "safely"... maybe it's not so safe.

If your computer's still so new, and still under warranty, and you still suspect a hardware problem I'd consider returning it to the store. If you bought it at a store that's got a good return policy (like walmart or futureshop) you might be able to flat out return it for a full refund within 30 days or whatever the store uses. Or if not a refund then at least warranty repair or exchange.

Or for the DIY troubleshooting there's always "take out a part, see if it works now, take out another part..." and try finding what's bad. Try only 1 ram stick, different video card, etc... Swapping the CPU might involve removing the heat sinks, cleaning, reapplying thermal paste, I'd save that for last (unless you get a kick out of it ;)

Additional thought:

*"Both times this has happened it was the first time after I got back from a LAN"* 
Do you mean a LAN party, where you get together with a bunch of people and play windows games & install new programs & stuff? Maybe you've caught some kind of virus or malware that's messed up your windows? If the ram seems good, and the HD seems good, maybe try a virus scan with something like ClamAV in Ubuntu, or there are some stand-alone antivirus "rescue cd"'s to try, I think they're like a linux live CD. Examples include http://www.avg.com/us-en/avg-rescue-cd or https://www.avira.com/en/download/product/avira-rescue-system (I don't know which is best, I just know they exist & found links to 2)
 Or maybe some important windows settings/files got changed (my accident or other) while at the party somehow, but unless it's a BIOS setting you should still be able to boot to the same windows install disk/usb that worked before. If you unplug the hard drive and verify that the BIOS settings still allow USB booting I'd try the windows USB  again, and if still no-go I'd try a known good windows DVD to make sure it's not a software or usb problem. (And removing/unpluging the HD is part of hardware troubleshooting anyway)

Comment: I have done a full memtest run which didn't come back with anything. I'm running a smart extended self-test right now. But I dont expect it to be the HDD because it has the same problem when running it from a USB which I know runs fine on other computers. It's from amazon and self built so I can return parts but I need to know what's broken first.

Comment: Is this an old computer's hard drive that you've moved into a new computer? If so, maybe it's the old windows' way of saying "I don't like all these hardware changes, I'm not going to run."

Comment: It's an old drive with a completely new install since the new computer that worked for the whole last month.

Comment: Added LAN (party?) to answer

Comment: I ran a virus scan, and it couldn't have changed my USB install 'disk' which will not even run, even without any of the disks present.